# Json parameter in POSTMAN with postgreSQL function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postman, postgrest

I have created the postgreSQL function below:

```
create or replace function analyse_lat(jsonvariable json) returns table (ok boolean, nb text) as 
$BODY$
declare 
    r record;
begin
    for r in (select * from json_to_recordset(jsonvariable->'list') as foo(id int, price1 numeric, price2 numeric)) loop
        --- DO THINGS
        ok:=(r.price1>r.price2);
        nb:='this is text returned';
        return next;
    end loop;
end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

it takes its format as input :

```
{
     "users":"John",
     "Level":"1",
     "list":[
      {"id":"1", "price1":"100.50", "price2":"90.50"},
      {"id":"2", "price1":"100.60", "price2":"80.50"},
      {"id":"2", "price1":"105.50", "price2":"700.50"}
    ]
}
```

However I can't test with POSTMAN
he interprets this as text and not JSON. do you have any ideas?

[image]

error message :

```
{
    "hint": "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",
    "details": null,
    "code": "42883",
    "message": "function analyse_lat(jsonvariable => text) does not exist"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try restarting PostgREST or sending it a SIGUSR1: `kill -s SIGUSR1 $(pgrep postgrest)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is type casting. The function expects parameters of types `INT` and `NUMERIC`.
You are passing these parameters to JSON as strings. Try changing the request body.

```
{
     "users":"John",
     "Level":"1",
     "list":[
      {"id":1, "price1":100.50, "price2":90.50},
      {"id":2, "price1":100.60, "price2":80.50},
      {"id":2, "price1":105.50, "price2":700.50}
    ]
}
```